# Nested Loop not working in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, function

I'm trying to implement a nested loop in Mysql without cursors.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION abc() 
RETURNS INT 
BEGIN DECLARE val INT;
DECLARE row,col INT DEFAULT 1;
SET val=1;
  row_loop: LOOP
      SET col=1;
      col_loop: LOOP
           SET col=col+1;
           SET val=val+1;
           IF col>8 THEN
              LEAVE col_loop;
          END IF;
      END LOOP col_loop;
      SET row=row+1;
      IF row>8 THEN
          LEAVE row_loop;
      END IF;
    RETURN val;
END LOOP row_loop;
END;
$$
```

The output should be 64 rather but I'm getting 8 as the inner loop is not running after 1st iteration.

Comment: It is unclear why you would want to do this.  But if you did, isn't `while` more appropriate?

Comment: I did try changing the outer loop to while but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine, except the return statement is *inside* the loop:

```
  row_loop: LOOP
      SET col=1;
      col_loop: LOOP
           SET col=col+1;
           SET val=val+1;
           IF col>8 THEN
              LEAVE col_loop;
          END IF;
      END LOOP col_loop;
      SET row=row+1;
      IF row>8 THEN
          LEAVE row_loop;
      END IF;
  END LOOP row_loop;
  RETURN val;
```

Comment: The loop doesn't seem to end, used Ctrl+c to abort the query.

Comment: @Golden_flash . . . You should set the value of `row` before the loop begins.  The `default` is only applying to `col`.